# Variadic function that takes array types

Tags: c++, variadic

Is there any way to write a variadic function that takes array types?

```
void compare(int count ...) {
    double[2] condition;
    va_list vl;    
    va_start(vl, count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        condition = va_arg(vl, double[2]);
        // do something with condition
    }
    va_end(vl);
}
```

I tried to do in C++, but my program says that `double[2]` types are not assignable.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 3):

Fixed arrays decay into a pointer to the 1st element.

Arrays are always passed to C style variadic parameters by pointer, eg:

```
void compare(int count, ...)
{
    double *condition;
    va_list vl;    
    va_start(vl, count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        condition = va_arg(vl, double*);
        // do something with condition up to 2 elements
    }
    va_end(vl);
}

int main()
{
    double arr1[2] = {1, 2};
    double arr2[2] = {3, 4};
    double arr3[2] = {5, 6};
    compare(3, arr1, arr2, arr3);
    return 0;
}
```

If you need to know the length of each passed array, you will have to pass in that info using additional variadic parameters, eg:

```
void compare(int count, ...)
{
    double *condition;
    int len;
    va_list vl;    
    va_start(vl, count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        len = va_arg(vl, int);
        condition = va_arg(vl, double*);
        // do something with condition, up to len elements
    }
    va_end(vl);
}

int main()
{
    double arr1[1] = {1};
    double arr2[5] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    double arr3[2] = {7, 8};
    compare(3, 1, arr1, 5, arr2, 2, arr3);
    return 0;
}
```

If you are using C++11 or later, you should use C++ style [variadic templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) instead of C style variadic parameters, eg:

```
template <size_t N>
void doSomething(double (&condition)[N])
{
    // do something with condition, up to N elements
}

template <size_t N>
void compare(double (&arr)[N])
{
    doSomething(arr);
}

template <size_t N, typename... Args>
void compare(double (&arr)[N], Args&... args)
{
    doSomething(arr);
    compare(args...);
}

int main()
{
    double arr1[1] = {1};
    double arr2[5] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    double arr3[2] = {7, 8};
    compare(arr1, arr2, arr3);
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/ZstmWA)